# pdf to word converter

Tags: pdf, ms-word, doc

Respected friends,

I just wanted to know which is the best professional software application to convert PDF to doc format.

One of the good software application i found through surfing is "NITRO" but is there any better software application which will convert even unique mathematical derivations and its symbols to its word formate.

As the software application cost a lot i wanted to know which s the best one among them. Please help me.

thanking u ,

Comment: If you are asking about which software application to use, Superuser.com is a better site.

Comment: I don't think this is the place to ask such question.. you can google it ( pdf2word ).. anyway - pdftoword seems OK to me, but I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as to convert PDF to Word, it will be easy to do with a pdf convertion tool like Advanced PDF Converter which allows you to [**convert pdf to word**](http://www.advancedpdfconverter.com),excel,ppt.what's more, it can also convert word to pdf files with ease.

Download it from advanced pdf converter official site.